# activity is restart when screen is rotate

Tags: android

I wonder why android:configChanges="orientation" could not work for android version 4.0.3.
When the screen is rotate the activity restart.

Please kindly help on this matter.

Rgds,
Virak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please also add screenSize like this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using orientation|screenSize (?) prevents onCreate on Android 4 and does not seem to break anything in previous Android versions.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

No idea why this is necessary and I don't really understand the documentation about this new value.

I suspect that in HONEYCOMB_MR2 upon an orientation change the activity considers this as two config changes: orientation and screen size. And both attempt to recreate the activity by default.